# Need old field values for records updated via Workbench

Tags: data, workbench

We had updated few QuoteLineItem records yesterday via Workbench.
We didn't take backup prior to updation...now we need to undo the whole operation.

but as we don't have backup with us right now.. we are unable to do that.

Can you please guide if there is anyway by which we can fetch the old field values updated by Workbench ?

If Salesforce can help us to fetch the old record values, if it's possible ?

Please help as it's very criticial for us.
Thank you.

Comment: If you have field history tracking enabled you are in luck. If not, without a backup you won't be able to recover the data.

Comment: @PhilW  Sure thank you

Comment: In the past, salesforce.com offered a data restore service. It was $10k and took weeks. Even at those prices, salesforce.com was still operating at a loss to provide the service, which involved copying a server and rewinding logs. These days, that service is no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Salesforce platform doesn't having any automatic backup data function. But You can get the old data in below ways in Salesforce,

- `Data Management >> Data Export >> Scheduled export` Option. If it's scheduled already you can get the old data in past scheduled date.(Only for those records already created on that time)
- If `Field History Tracking` is already enabled for those fields means you can get that old data due to it's capture the every change in that field.

If you're not `Scheduled Export` and not enabled `Field History` means, You need to raise a Support ticket into Salesforce support team to check whether it's possible to get that old data.

Thanks.